# How to avoid saving after create? Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
def create
    @user = User.create(user_params)
    if @user.valid?
        charge = StripeWrapper::Charge.create(amount: 999, card: params[:stripeToken], description: "Sign up charge for #{@user.email}" )
        if charge.successful?
            @user.save
            User.inviter_and_invited_follow_each_other(@user)
            AppMailer.delay.welcome(current_user)
            session[:user_id] = @user.id
            flash[:notice] = "You have successfully registered and will be logged in."
            redirect_to root_path
        else
            flash[:notice] = charge.error_message
            render :new
        end
    else
        render :new
    end
end
```

User saves even when charge.successful? returns false. Nothing else happens as in no email is sent, session[:user_id] isn't set nor is it redirected to root_path. Else block executes and renders :new and displays a flash notice saying card is declined.

I am trying to avoid the user creation if charge.successful? returns false. Any idea on how to go about this?

Answer (score 5):

The `create` method is basically a combination of doing `@user = User.new` followed by `@user.save`.

So you can just use `.new` instead of `.create`. That way, it'll only be persisted to the database when you call `.save`:

```
@user = User.new(user_params)
```

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I didn't figure this out. Time for a break!